# karate.io.github.classgraph.ClassGraphException: Uncaught exception during scan and java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: spring-boot, karate

Getting this error while trying to run a single Karate API test
And also Added @SpringBootTest, @AutoConfiguration and @TestResourceProperty in the runner file and also tried increasing the heap space to 4096MB still the same error.

> 

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.intuit.karate.Runner$Builder.resolveAll(Runner.java:276)
    at com.intuit.karate.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:168)
    at com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate.iterator(Karate.java:59)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.spliterator(Iterable.java:101)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
>>Caused by: karate.io.github.classgraph.ClassGraphException: Uncaught exception during scan
    at karate.io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.scan(ClassGraph.java:1570)
    at karate.io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph.scan(ClassGraph.java:1587)
    at com.intuit.karate.resource.ResourceUtils.<clinit>(ResourceUtils.java:94)
    ... 55 more
>>>Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:88)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at karate.nonapi.io.github.classgraph.utils.FileUtils.sanitizeEntryPath(FileUtils.java:181)
    at karate.nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.LogicalZipFile.readCentralDirectory(LogicalZipFile.java:620)
    at karate.nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.LogicalZipFile.<init>(LogicalZipFile.java:154)
    at karate.nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.NestedJarHandler$3.newInstance(NestedJarHandler.java:144)
    at karate.nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.NestedJarHandler$3.newInstance(NestedJarHandler.java:139)
    at karate.nonapi.io.github.classgraph.concurrency.SingletonMap.get(SingletonMap.java:189)
    at karate.nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.NestedJarHandler$4.newInstance(NestedJarHandler.java:205)
    at karate.nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.NestedJarHandler$4.newInstance(NestedJarHandler.java:154)
    at karate.nonapi.io.github.classgraph.concurrency.SingletonMap.get(SingletonMap.java:189)
    at karate.io.github.classgraph.ClasspathElementZip.open(ClasspathElementZip.java:162)
    at karate.io.github.classgraph.Scanner$3.processWorkUnit(Scanner.java:595)
    at karate.io.github.classgraph.Scanner$3.processWorkUnit(Scanner.java:567)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: certainly sounds like an area we need your contribution. karate uses the classgraph library and looks like it conflicts with some spring stuff. if you want help make sure you follow this process so that we can replicate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution:
Just add a plugin in pom.xml and set fork = 1 as done below:-

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```